# Angular Demo app

Tags: angularjs

I've been learning Angular and hit a strange wall . . . first off I ran an angular demo using DEPLOYD and SERVER.JS and everything ran fine.  I also ran another that hits a RESTful web service online, and it ran fine.  So I take what seems to be the next logical step and create my own RESTful web service and it deploys to TOMCAT just fine.  I can query the service in my browser to localhost, and it runs fine.  So far so good.

So, I build a very simple Angular app to hit that service and nothing gets returned.  OK, I figure I messed something up . . . so I mod my demo app to hit a DEPLOYD instance, and it works.  I mod it to his the existing service, and it works . . . but when I point it to my own RESTful service nothing gets returned.  I can't afford to lose any more hair over this.  Here are some particulars:

When tested in the browser, my service is returning:

```
    [{"person":{"id":1,"fullName":"Alpha","age":10}},{"person":{"id":2,"fullName":"Bravo","age":20}},{"person":{"id":3,"fullName":"Charlie","age":30}},{"person":{"id":4,"fullName":"Delta","age":40}},{"person":{"id":5,"fullName":"Echo","age":50}},{"person":{"id":6,"fullName":"Foxtrot","age":60}}]
```

A pretty simple JSON array, right?

Here is my HTML:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html ng-app>
    <head>
        <title>Hello AngularJS</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8    /angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="hello.js"></script>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>

    <body>
    <div ng-controller="Hello">
        <div class="well" ng-repeat="person in data.person">
            <h3>
                <strong>{{person.id}}</strong>
                <span class="pull-right label label-primary">
                    {{person.age}}
                </span>
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And here is my controller javascript:

```
    function Hello($scope, $http) {

        $scope.data = {};
        $http.get("http://localhost:8085/TestWS/service/getAllPersonsInJSON").
            success(function(data) {
                $scope.data.person = data;
            });
        @scope.data.person();
    }
```

I pared it down to the essentials, I think . . . but no joy getting data displayed.  Anyone care to help me avoid making a larger bald spot?

TIA,
     Ted

Comment: @scope.data.person();  whats this line suppose to do?

Comment: This is most likely due to CORS, and that your RESTful service isn't set up to allow this origin

Comment: Agree with the CORS suggestion. Also, once you get that working, each `person` has a `person` property. So the bindings should really be `{{person.person.id}}` and `{{person.person.age}}`.

Comment: Researching CORS now, fingers crossed to avoid more hairpulling

Comment: Doesn't look like CORS should be an issue for such a simple request.  WIll keep researching.

Comment: CORS shouldn't be the issue.  I am running on a local instance of TOMCAT on port 8085 and a server.js webserver on port 5000.  if CORS was the issue, wouldn't the straight HTML request hit the same barrier?

Comment: I have deployed CORS to my container, and redelyed the container.  I modded the call to use a CORS request . . . and still not joy.

Comment: Oh, and I checked the HTML request, and the server is still serving up the JSON data just like before . . no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to run this on my machine.

The issue looks like with nesting of data to an extra step. 
The data you are receiving is a json array, to display this I directly assigned it to person.
Made these changes to controller : 
removed $scope.data = {};

So controller had the below 3 lines.

```
 $http.get("url").
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.person = data;
        });
```

Then accessed the data in HTML file :

```
<div ng-controller="Hello">
    <div class="well" ng-repeat="person in person">
            <h3>
              person is 
                <strong>{{person.person.id}}</strong>
                <span class="pull-right label label-primary">
                    {{person.person.age}}
                </span>
            </h3>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Hope it will help.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line as that's not really valid Angular code and person isn't a function.

```
@scope.data.person();
```

Everything else looks great.

Comment: I shouldn't have included that . . . that one was one of my hair-brained attempted fixes.  Without that line, still no joy.

Comment: @TedHerrlich Are you loading NG right? Looks like you have a huge space in this script that is loading Angular, after the 1.0.8 which probably shouldn't be there.

Comment: The space is an error in the editor here, it's not really there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $scope.data.person = data.data;
```

This is because, the $http.Get(function(data){},..) will return http response packet in data variable. In order to access the data inside http response packet, you've to access data.data object.

Edit:
If above workaround donot works, use console.log(data) inside success callback and have a look at browser's console to inspect what data is being actually passed on by the success callback function.

Hope this helps.